# Play Framework Form Error Handling

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

This is my view file containing the form that has to filled in by the user:

```
@helper.form(call) {
    @helper.input(resumeForm("surname"), '_label -> "Surname") { (id, name, value, args) =>
        <input name="@name" type="text" value="@value" placeholder="Enter your surname">
    }
}
```

This is my custom field constructor:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@if(!elements.args.isDefinedAt('showLabel) || elements.args('showLabel) == true) {
    <div class="input-with-label text-left">
        <span>@elements.label</span>
        @elements.input
    </div>
} else {
    @elements.input
}
```

Now I have a dilemma. When the entered value doesn't clear validation, I need to add the class `field-error` to the input and I need to add `data-toggle`, `data-placement` and `title`. However, I don't know of any way to check if there are errors for the specific field. What is the best way to implement this? I already looked at using `inputText` or something but that is basically the same as the base `input` thus also does not have access to any errors. I'm also unable to alter the HTML of the `elements.input` inside the field constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [play documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors): *Writing your own field constructor*.
You can check on errors with `@if(elements.hasErrors)` within the template of your custom field constructor.

```
<div class="input-with-label text-left @if(elements.hasErrors){field-error}">
    ...
```

**Edit:**

You can pass the error state of your field via the `args` parameter to your input. From the play docs:

> **Note:** All extra parameters will be added to the generated HTML, except for ones whose name starts with the _ character. Arguments starting with an underscore are reserved for field constructor argument (which we will see later).

You need to cast to the matching type though.

```
@input(resumeForm("surname"), '_label -> "Surname", 'hasErrors -> resumeForm("surname").hasErrors) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input name="@name" type="text" value="@value" placeholder="Enter your surname"
        class="@if(args.get('hasErrors).map(_ match { case x:Boolean => x}).get){field-error}">
}
```

Comment: That's what I said. This will not solve my problem because I can't alter the input using this.

Comment: Never really understood what they meant with that sentences haha. Thanks!